# How to pass arguments to parent class with inheritance and with super keyword?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

My program is shown below:

```
class BioData:
    def __init__(self, FirstName, LastName):
        self.FirstName = FirstName
        self.LastName = LastName

class BioData_OP(BioData):
    def __init__(self, age, address):
        super().__init__(FirstName,LastName)
        self.age = age
        self.address = address

mydata = BioData_OP(36,"CNGF","Big","Bee")
```

I am getting an error. I know if I pass two arguments it won't give me an error but in that case how I can get the first name and last name?

I do not want to initialize their values in class `BioData_OP`. Do I need to create a separate object for BioData? if yes then what is the benefit of using inheritance or the `super` keyword.

Comment: Where do you expect `BioData_OP.__init__` to get values for `FirstName` and `LastName` from? (by the way, you shouldn't name variable identifiers and function parameters with capitals)

Comment: @GinoMempin I updated it, thank you. I want it to get the values from the user.

Comment: Your `BioData_OP`'s `__init__` is only accepting `age` and `address` during initialization. You need to also let it accept the firstname and lastname, and then pass that to `super`.

Comment: Your more general question more or less shows why it's a bad idea to change the signature of the constructor for a subclass. Since you change the constructor, someone constructing an instance of `BioData_OP` will need to provide more arguments than someone constructing an instance of `BioData` - so although `BioData_OP` says it's a `BioData`, it isn't in that respect.

Comment: How I can do it without changing the constructor ?

Comment: @Grismar Are you saying I should use this approach `class BioData_OP:
    def __init__(self, FirstName, LastName, age, address):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of inheritance is to indicate that a certain class (ex. `Dog`) has an "*is a*" relationship with a parent class (ex. `Animal`). So, a `Dog` *is an* `Animal` but with certain properties that only dogs have (or appropriate only to dogs).

```
class Animal:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

class Dog(Animal):
  def __init__(self, name, breed):
    super().__init__(name)
    self.breed = breed

a_dog = Dog("woolfie", "labrador")
```

Here, the `__init__` still takes a `name`, but also takes in extra attributes specific for a dog, such as `breed`. For the common attribute `name`, that's where you can just pass it along to the parent class with `super`.

---

So, applying that to your code, I'm assuming a `BioData_OP` object *is a* type of `BioData`, but with added `age` and `address` attributes. The `__init__` should probably still accept the same first name and last name, but then just have added parameters for `age` and `address`.

```
class BioData:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name

class BioData_OP(BioData):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age, address):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name)
        self.age = age
        self.address = address

mydata = BioData_OP("Big","Bee", 36,"CNGF")
```

---

[As recommended in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70981175/how-to-pass-arguments-to-parent-class-with-inheritance-and-with-super-keyword/70981265#comment125480528_70981265), depending on your intended use-case or situation, if this going to be part of a factory design pattern, you should make sure not to change the base class' initialization, but instead, let your subclass accept optional values for subclass-specific values or provide a separate method for setting those values.

```
class BioData:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name

class BioData_OP(BioData):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age=-1, address=None):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name)
        self.age = age
        self.address = address

    def update(self, age, address):
        self.age = age
        self.address = address

# Still works
# Will create a BioData_OP object but without age and address
# Basically creates a BioData object
mydata_1 = BioData_OP("Big","Bee")

# Directly create a BioData_OP object
mydata_2 = BioData_OP("Big","Bee", 36,"CNGF")

# First, create a BioData object
# Then, turn in into a BioData_OP object
mydata_3 = BioData_OP("Big","Bee")
mydata_3.update(36, "CNGF")
```

Comment: This is the correct way of doing it, if you want to do it at all. An improvement might be to provide a default value for `age` and `address`, since the superclass doesn't expect `age` or `address` and a factory looking to produce a `BioData_OP` as well as instances of the superclass or other subclasses may be unable to provide the added arguments. For that same reason, you could choose to set such additional attributes through a new method, which could be called from the constructor, or expected to be called after construction.